# Is this a Starling Egg in a Robin's Nest?

Tags: birds, bird-behaviour, robins

Robins built a nest on a trellis in front of my deck.  I was curious and peeked inside when the bird was away.  There was one blue egg.  A few days later I saw a starling walking around this nest.

Just now, I took another peek inside.  This time there were three eggs, but one does not look like the others.

Did the starling lay its egg in this robin's nest?  This nest is located in Northern New Jersey.

[image: Robin's Nest with Suspicious Egg]

Comment: More likely to be a cuckoo.

Comment: Just to check: Europe/UK? Starlings are widespread and the other side of the Atlantic they have a thrush they call a Robin.

Comment: @ChrisH, I updated the question with the location (Northern New Jersey, USA). I was confused by websites that identified these blue eggs differently and realize now that European robins/starlings have different egg characteristics from Northern American ones. Thank you for asking for clarification.

Comment: @ChrisH The birds that built this nest are most certainly North American robins  - https://www.britannica.com/animal/American-robin

Comment: The Common/European Starling was introduced to the US (in 1890 by [Schieffelin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eugene_Schieffelin)), so could be the same species, but Common Cuckoo as mentioned in @WeatherVane's answer is a vagrant your side of the Atlantic. I rarely see European Robins' eggs, but they're not blue unlike yours.  However yours can be speckled apparently.  [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/American_robin) says that Brown-headed Cowbirds can be brood parasites of American Robins.  Brood parasitism has been exhibited by Starlings too.

Comment: I think I need to write an answer - not a conclusive one but there's a lot of interesting material to put together

Comment: @ChrisH if the eggs are indeed cuckoo eggs, it would not be a Common Cuckoo but most likely a Yellow-billed Cuckoo which is relatively common in NJ. Yellow-billeds are not exclusively brood parasites that lay eggs in other birds' nests, but apparently they are capable of doing so: https://ebird.org/atlasmddc/news/may-2021-bird-of-the-month-yellow-billed-cuckoo?tagId=2

Comment: @qdread not as distinctive a call as ours, but still we have no evidence of cuckoos at all. The first mention of any cuckoo species was in the context of an assumption that this was in Europe, in the answer below.

Comment: Evidence of Starlings being brood parasites of other species (as well as, much more commonly, their own): https://sciendo.com/pdf/10.2478/orhu-2019-0020

Comment: @ChrisH - [Shakespeare](https://www.nytimes.com/2022/04/11/science/starlings-birds-shakespeare.html) strikes again.

Answer (score 8):

Perhaps there are now eggs of *three* species - **robin**, **starling** and **cuckoo**.

Starlings do attempt to take over others birds' nests, see [European Starling Life History](https://www.allaboutbirds.org/guide/European_Starling/lifehistory)

> Starlings often take over the nests of native birds, expelling the occupants.

[Optics Mag](https://opticsmag.com/starling-eggs-vs-robin-eggs/) also says

> However, [starlings] are invasive and can take over other birds’ nests and even kill them.

Cuckoos simply lay their egg, and when it hatches, their chick expels the others. The [RSPB](https://www.rspb.org.uk/birds-and-wildlife/wildlife-guides/bird-a-z/cuckoo/) says

> When a female cuckoo finds a suitable nest, and the hosts aren’t looking, she removes one of their eggs and lays her own egg in its place. Cuckoo young hatch after just 12 days, and push the hosts’ eggs or babies out of the nest, allowing it to eat all food brought by the host bird.

Identifying the three similar eggs, the two smaller ones are probably robin and starling. [Optics Mag](https://opticsmag.com/starling-eggs-vs-robin-eggs/) has this picture, which shows that starling eggs are larger and paler than the robin's egg. So the egg at the top of the OP's nest would be starling, with robin on the left.

[image]

The cuckoo egg is usually larger than the host's eggs, and is often mottled, such as the selection shown below, from [Cosmos magazine](https://cosmosmagazine.com/nature/evolution/cuckoo-evolution-eggs-genetics). The cuckoo evolves its mimicry according to the other species in its habitat. Its egg will be the one on the right of the OP's photo.

[image]

Comment: Cuckoos are pretty rare, but they're very vocal with a call that carries a long way. If they're not heard in the neighbourhood in spring, they're quite unlikely

Comment: Are we sure the egg on the right in the OP is mottled and not just dirty?  It's hard to tell from the photo.

Comment: Unfortunately, the only cuckoos in this Northern New Jersey area, where this nest is located, are some of the neighbors.  No Cuckoo birds have ever been observed, but I agree the eggs in your example look similar to one in the photo.

Comment: I replaced the original photo with new one this is closer and clearer. (The reference locations in this reply no longer point to the same eggs.  This new photo is taken one day later and the robin appears to have rotated the eggs 60-degrees clockwise.